# add a blank space to combobox to clear selection

Tags: c#, combobox

I serched and serached and no solution for this problem.
I have several `comboboxes` that get values from `sql` to filter some data in a table, the problem is when the user selects a `combobox` if he wants to clear it it has no option to do so, only select another item.

After some search i added a `button` to clear the `comboboxes` but i dont want that solution, what i was thinking is create a blank space in each combobox to clear the selection.

How can i create such a space that the user can select if he wants to remove the selection.
CODE:

```
 private void vidro_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct desempenho from vidros", con);
            DataTable DTT = new DataTable();
            SDA.Fill(DTT);
            desempenho.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT.Rows)
            {
                desempenho.Items.Add(ROW["desempenho"].ToString());
            }
            SqlDataAdapter SDA2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct valu from vidros", con);
            DataTable DTT2 = new DataTable();
            SDA2.Fill(DTT2);
            valu.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT2.Rows)
            {
                valu.Items.Add(ROW["valu"].ToString());
            }
            SqlDataAdapter SDA3 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct fs from vidros", con);
            DataTable DTT3 = new DataTable();
            SDA3.Fill(DTT3);
            fsolar.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT3.Rows)
            {
                fsolar.Items.Add(ROW["fs"].ToString());
            }
            SqlDataAdapter SDA5 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct compo from vidros", con);
            DataTable DTT5 = new DataTable();
            SDA5.Fill(DTT5);
            select.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT5.Rows)
            {
                compo.Items.Add(ROW["compo"].ToString());
            }
            SqlDataAdapter SDA6 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct sel from vidros", con);
            DataTable DTT6 = new DataTable();
            SDA6.Fill(DTT6);
            select.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT6.Rows)
            {
                select.Items.Add(ROW["sel"].ToString());
            }
        }
        private void compo_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillData();
        }
        private void select_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillData();
        }
        private void fsolar_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillData();
        }
        private void valu_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillData();
        }
        private void desempenho_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillData();
        }
        private void FillData()
        {
            string combo1value = desempenho.Text;
            string combo2value = valu.Text;
            string combo3value = fsolar.Text;
            string combo4value = select.Text;
            string combo5value = compo.Text;

            string query = "select [descri],[enchimento],[compo] from vidros where 1=1 ";
            string queryWhere = "";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just insert an empty item as the first in you item collection. If you show us some code, we could help further

Comment: @Pikoh ok code added. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let´s just use one of your comboboxes as example:

```
desempenho.Items.Clear();
foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT.Rows)
{
     desempenho.Items.Add(ROW["desempenho"].ToString());
}
desempenho.Items.Items.Insert(0,"");
```

This way you'll have an empty item as the first one in your combo, then you'll have to check it when validating the form.

Comment: It works, but there is a problem, now i get 8 blank spaces instead of 1

Comment: Make sure you put the `desempenho.Items.Items.Insert(0,"");` outside the `foreach`